# Package javax.servlet.jsp error

Tags: java, maven, jsp

I have an error in a .jsp file in my java ee project : **package javax.servlet.jsp does not exist**. I have searched why and I found that with Maven, we need to add a dependency into the pom.xml. But I already have this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I build the project, it tells me "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" but I still have this error. Is there anything I need to add somewhere else please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sorry, you're right, the error disapeared ! :) Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

ultimately `servlet-api.jar` should be in classpath i.e under WEB-INF\lib folder

Comment: Thanks ! I'm working on Netbeans and I have a WEB-INF but it contains only web.xml. Should I add it in the "dependencies" ?

Comment: I looked, and I already have the servlet-api.jar in Dependencies